# Do GUI stuffs on the doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I read about asyncTask and learnt that onPostExecute and onPrExecute are used to update the UI while doInBackground is used to do heavy operation on another thread.

I was wondering, would it be "bad" to do GUI update on the DoInBackGround. For example, displaying a Toast etc.

Why I want to do that?  Because sometime I want to use the results of this long operations to display things and  I don't want to have private variables in my task just to store them for GUI purposes

thank you

Comment: Why the downvote? it is a legitimate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doInbackground itself means do me in background not on foreground. Thing what you are looking for can be achieved by publishProgress(). 
Further still if you don't want to use it then try to run another thread in doInbackground method with runOnUi support..

Comment: hmmm Makes sense. So what happens if  I display toast from the DoInBackground? I tried it and it works. Would it fail or just not coding standard

Comment: it might be displayed delayed, it might break with future sdk releases, it might not work with old ones etc etc - just so many reasons not to code against the standard particular when there is a clean solution - in your case publishProgress - to achieve what you want -- my take on that ...

Comment: if do things in good manner they'll perform best. If android supports this then why do you need to add another thread in already background working thread?? Further more its not a good coding practice..:P